# What are the exact specifications of a RushFPV SMA connector?

Tags: hardware, antenna

I am designing a mount for a RushFPV SMA connector and have not been able to find the technical details.

I need:

The diameter of the connector

The distance between the mounting screw holes

The dimensions of the mounting plate in which the holes are cut.

If anyone has this information, I would be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Not to beat up on https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/216/how-can-i-configure-a-servo-in-betaflight, but this is what I would consider an excellent question. It asks a specific question, the answer will never get stale, and there's no easy support via the manufacturer.

Comment: @Kenn Sebesta, I think you're going to find that expectations and culture of this stack will be quite different from a lot of other parts of Stack Exchange. That's ok though :D The DIY drone community kind of already has an established subculture that will be represented here. I believe it will still develop into a thriving community with a lot of good information and contributing experts.

Comment: Yup, that's what the beta is all about! I figure if I want to see researchers hop aboard my job is to _gently_ push for more questions about esoteric connectors and fewer about bland autopilot configuration. P.S. I might have been involved in the drone community for an odd decade now. ;)

Comment: @KennSebesta wow, that puts my five odd years to shame!

Comment: @DronesandWhatnot, pff, hardly. I'm so impressed by how quickly SE.Drones came together. Ever since the days of Mikrokopter and OpenPilot, I've been dying for one. Kudos to you guys for this initiative.

Comment: @KennSebesta it’s awesome how quickly this is growing! And thank you, I’d live to be able to accept your kudos but all credit should go to the people who petitioned to get this SE created - I’m just a random guy who loves to ask and answer questions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Rush cable is slightly non-standard as it lacks the threads on the holes that the TBS connectors have. It works fine though. The SMA is a standard SMA thread, so the normal hole size for SMA connectors works well. In my designs I usually use a 6.5mm hole for SMA, though some of that depends on the tolerances you're dealing with on your machining. The hole spacing for the small mounting holes is 11.5 mm from center to center. I usually use a 1.5mm hole for the bolt for the Rush SMA mounts, as you can thread an M2 bolt right into the carbon without needing an additional nut, but if you're wanting to use a nut, you'll want to increase that to a 2mm hole.

[image: Rush SMA dimension Data]

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I was looking for - thank you! Rather annoyingly, I half-remembered a source that they were M3 holes so I now have a useless mount printing! Thanks again for the info - it’ll make redesigning much easier.

Comment: The holes are M2.5 I believe, they will fit a 2.5mm bolt. The M2 bolts are a bit loose but 2.5mm bolts are a bit harder to find, so I usually just go for M2, since I have tons of them.

Comment: I’m that case, my mount should work if I use a screw with a wide enough head. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Also worth noting the above dimensions will work for TBS as well, but you'd definitely want to go 2mm holes, as the TBS mount is threaded.

Comment: This is really helpful, but could you link to where this data come from? One of the most important features of SE sites is reference links. It's what separates good answers from great ones.

Comment: This came from my brain unfortunately. I have the connector, took the measurements, and designed the holes and cut the prototypes myself.