# How to add servo control on my fpv drone to drop a parachute or other object

Tags: servo

I have a DARWINFPV BETAFLIGHT F4 FC 50A 2-6S BLHELI_S 4IN1 DSHOT600 ESC STACK. I'm looking to add on a servo that i can control while flying so that i can drop objects, move a camera around, deploy a parachute, etc. I have a flysky transmitter with a FLI14+ reciever, and 2 open AUX channels.

I've followed tutorials from here: [How can I configure a servo in Betaflight?](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/216/how-can-i-configure-a-servo-in-betaflight/230#230) and I don't know where the extra motor pads are on my flight controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look at [the manual for that flight controller](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0585/5841/5023/files/STACK002.pdf?v=1631950760), and unfortunately it doesn't seem to provide any pads where you could access the AUX channels.

I don't think adding a servo to that flight controller will be possible.

Comment: So with that flight controller would adding a servo even be possible?